# Is it possible to create a numpy matrix with 10 rows and 0 columns?

Tags: python, numpy

My objective is to start with an "empty" matrix and repeatedly add columns to it until I have a large matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
>>> a = np.zeros((10, 0))
>>> a.shape
(10, 0)
```

You can then use [`ndarray.resize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html#numpy.ndarray.resize) to expand it after the fact without copying. This has some problems though, and for many applications it'll be easier to use a list of vectors that you then merge into a single array.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I should have tested this myself.

Comment: yeah but then I wouldn't have found this question to do what I wanted, which is create a large data set in Python for memory use test cases.

Answer (score 2):

Add columns to ndarray(or matrix) need full copy of the content, so you should use other method such as list or the array module, or create a large matrix first, and fill data in it.